# Inverted Mouse Axis on a Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, mouse, live-usb

I have an Ubuntu Live USB and I was looking for xorg.conf so I could insert an Option "InvX" "on" within it (I am not quite sure how that works exactly yet). xorg.conf does not exist in its normal place on the live usb/cd. Where can I easily and permanently make this change?

Background:
I am running ubuntu on a kiosk machine where mouse movement works like a touch screen (sort of).

Comment: I've tried to address the issue of how to invert the mouse axis, but I don't exactly understand what you mean by "like a touch screen (sort of)". Please elaborate and I will try to make my answer more relevant to the question.

Comment: Its not exactly a touch screen, they kinda faked it with some sort of laser thing close to the screen. In any case, your solution worked just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xorg.conf is, for all intents and purposes, no longer there. But there is now a directory, `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, that keeps configuration options for x.org.

A side note: In **10.04 Lucid**, the directory is `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

To invert the mouse movement:

- Create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-invertaxes.conf`

  - to create this file, you need to gain root privileges. Start your favourite text-editor like this: `gksu gedit`. This will prompt you for a password.
  - alternatively, you can type this into a Terminal:

    ```
    sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-invertaxes.conf
    ```
- Put the following into the file:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
      Identifier  "Invert Mouse"
      MatchProduct    "The name our your mouse in xorg"
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      Option      "InvertY"       "true"
      Option      "InvertX"       "true"
  EndSection
  ```

  Where you replace "the name of your mouse in xorg" with the real name as detected by xorg.
- to find out what Identifer you need to use, open a terminal and type

  ```
  xinput list
  ```

  this will produce output similar to this:

  ```
  ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
  ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  [more...]
  ```

  From there I can see the Identifier of my Logitech mouse, `Logitech USB Reciever`.

To be able to keep this configuration, you will have to have set up your Live USB drive with "Persistent storage":

[image: old screenshot of usb startup disk creator]

Enable the option at the bottom, "Stored in reserved extra space", before creating your new USB startup disk and your settings will be kept when rebooting.

Comment: By the way, after I created 50-invertedaxes.conf I simply restarted and it worked just fine. No other configuration was needed to make it persistent. I should note that I used the Linux Live USB generator as instructed by ubuntu.com with the netbook remix iso.